# Unable to pass reference of array to method in C

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

I create a char array and want to pass a reference to it to a method which populates the array.

```
char binary[BYTE_LEN];
readBinaryInput(&binary);
```

The method is as follows.

```
void readBinaryInput(char *binaryString[]) {

    printf("Enter an 8-bit binary string.\n");
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < BYTE_LEN; i++) {
        scanf("%s", binaryString[i]);
    }

}
```

When I run the program calling the method, I get the following errors.

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'readBinaryInput' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
readBinaryInput(&binary);

note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char (*)[8]'
void readBinaryInput(char *binaryString[]) {
```

I thought I was passing an address (`&binary`) to the method for the pointer argument to point to. Why am I getting errors telling me that `char **` is expected?

Comment: `binary` is not a pointer, it's an address. Therefore, `&binary` is just a pointer, not a double star pointer. I mean, the function decoration `void readBinaryInput(char binaryString[])` would suffice; try it w/o the `*`.

Comment: @ssd `binary` is a char array (`char[]`), not an address. It depends on where it is used.

Comment: @bool3max: Not exactly! An array returns the **absolute** memory address, where the data is actually laid upon; whereas, a pointer is a `sizeof(uintptr_t)` length memory space, pointing the address where the data is laid upon. You'd better test the code pasted [here](https://codeshare.io/arWn9A) or [here](https://controlc.com/173cf8b2).

Comment: @ssd Your example has nothing to do with the comment I posted. It talks about the address that the pointer is pointing to versus the address of the at which the pointer is stored (located). I was talking about the notion of an array being decayed to a pointer in certain instances, and not in others. For example, when used as an argument to the `sizeof` operator it does **not** decay: `sizeof(binary)` per OP's example would return `BYTE_LEN`, **not** `sizeof(uintptr_t)`. When used as an rvalue or as an argument to a function it will decay to a pointer to the first element of that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simply removing the `&` from `&binary` and the `*` from `char *binaryString[]`.

`char binary[BYTE_LEN]` is already a pointer (essentially equivalent to `char*`). It is a pointer to the first byte in your char array.  Treat it as such.